# A series of commands

Tags: articles

This is from a book

> John turned to the workstation and typed **a** series of commands.

Why is there an  "a". Is it a plural, right? So, why the indefinite article in this case?

Comment: Series is the form for both singular and plural: a series, many series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of commands, but there is only one series of commands. (Note that "series" is a singular noun, even though it ends in "s." Confusingly, its plural is also "series.")

Similar usage:

I want a set of chairs.
I am going to roll a pair of dice.